# Why is the second operation of a Monad called bind?

Tags: terminology, functional-programming

I understand how monadic computation works, I am just wondering where does the name come from. I cannot relate the thing that the `bind` operator actually does (i.e. unbox the monadic value, and then apply a function to produce another monadic value) and the name `bind` (which, to me, means associate two things together).

I understand why we have the name `return` (I suspect it has to do with the Haskell do-notation), although IMHO it isn't a good name either. Return indicates a change in control flow but it really isn't, all it does is produce a monadic value.

Comment: If it helps, other languages use other names. Ive seen flatMap and SelectMany before too.

Answer (score 5):

In Haskell the syntactic sugar for `bind e₁ (λ x . e₂)` is

```
do x ← e₁
   e₂
```

That is, the result of the computation `e₁` is *bound* to `x`, after which `e₂` is computed.

In ML-like languages the same thing is written as

```
let x = e₁ in e₂
```

which again is a form of binding a variable to a value.

As for `return` being a control-flow mechanism – that's precisely what it is. You are probably thinking of control mechanisms for branching, looping, raising exceptions etc. Well, `return` is the one that ends a computation and yields a result.

Comment: Caution: Unlike imperative settings where a `return` causes *immediate end of computation*, in Haskell and in monads in-general, a `return` *in the middle* is a form of local-naming ;-)

Comment: @MusaAl-hassy: The return we are discussing here is *not* the `return` from Python, C, Java, etc., so I do not what you're trying to say. You're mixing oranges and apples, I think. The `return` from a monad is something like "pure value" in imperative languages, not returning from a subroutine.

Answer (score 4):

In λ-calculus, the term $\lambda x. y$ binds $x$ in $y$. Once a value is given to $x$, any well-scoped reference to $x$ in $y$ will be replaced by that same value.

Function composition $(f\circ g)$ can be seen as an operator that binds the result of $g$ to $f$'s argument. In a similar way, you can view `bind : Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b` as an operator that binds the contents (the value underneath the monadic wrapper) of its first argument to the function supplied as its 2nd argument (`a -> m b`).

What if the 1st argument of type `m a` is the result of some previously applied function? In general, you can make consecutive applications of `bind` to mimic something like function composition, but under a monad.